# Why does deallocation function called with one argument instead of two?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I've been trying to understand the following behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct A
{ 
    void operator delete[](void *p)
    {
        cout << "delete\n";
        ::operator delete[](p);
    }

    void operator delete[](void *p, size_t t)
    {
        cout << "delete with two arguments\n";
        ::operator delete[](p);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A *a = new A[5];
    delete [] a;
}
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77686324d41d8783)

In the example non-placement deallocation function with **one** parameter is called. But 5.3.6/10 N3797 C++14 working draft said that:

> If the type is complete and if deallocation function lookup finds both
>   a usual deallocation function with only a pointer parameter and a
>   usual deallocation function with both a pointer parameter and a size
>   parameter, then the selected deallocation function shall be the one
>   **with two parameters**.

Is it a bug?

Comment: Exactly which version of which compiler are you using; exactly how did you invoke the compiler; and which version of the C++ standard are you quoting?

Comment: delete[] expressions that use global array deallocation functions, always call single-argument signatures

Comment: Also, which version of the standard are you looking at? I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: @JosephMansfield I work with N3797. I've updated my Q.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour By the way, has N3936 already been published?

Comment: Okay, this isn't in the C++11 standard. It looks like it might be a bug with the C++11 standard, because I can't see any mention of it. The compilers are just making a guess at what to do. The text you quoted is in both N3797 and N3936. Might be worth looking through the issues lists over the last few years.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv it is available via github see [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents#comment36876555_4653479)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That rule is new in C++14, and you're compiling under the C++11 standard. Specifying `-std=c++14` makes no difference, so presumably that compiler hasn't implemented that particular rule yet. Which isn't particularly surprising, since C++14 hasn't been officially published yet.

Answer (score 2):

So this is a new C++1y rule but we can see from [defect report 1788](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1788) the language may be changed to the following:

> the function to be called is selected as follows:

- If the type is complete and if, for the second alternative (delete array) only, the operand is a pointer to a class type with a non-trivial destructor or a (possibly multi-dimensional) array thereof, the function with two parameters is selected.
- Otherwise, it is unspecified which of the two deallocation functions is selected.

Answer (score 0):

In 3.7.4.2/2 of N3797, it says:

> if a class T has a member deallocation function named operator
>   delete[] with exactly one parameter, then that function is a usual
>   (non-placement) deallocation function. If class T does not declare
>   such an operator delete[] but does declare a member deallocation
>   function named operator delete[] with exactly two parameters, the
>   second of which has type std::size_t, then this function is a usual
>   deallocation function.

Since you have the single parameter delete[] function, that is the one that gets called.